# Brother laserjet doesn't print until restart is selected, model HL-L8360CDW

Tags: drivers, printing

Using 20.04LTS, Brother printer model HL-L8360CDW is connected to a network of Linux only computers.
After sending a print-job no printing happens.  Calling up "settings" I find the printer has errored and a message tells me to "fix the problem" and then select "Restart". The only problem appears to be imaginary in nature.  There is no indication as to what this "error" is and selecting "Restart" seems to fix the problem until I need to print again. This is a "repeating" problem.
Since my other Linux computers are not having this issue I'm thinking this is a "Ubuntu" only problem.
Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?  The computer operator is not an administrator.